# How to write call back functions for text positioning operators to get text position in pdf search in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

In my iPad app I need to highlight the searched pdf word. I used text showing operators TJ,Tj for finding the text in a pdf document but not able to highlight the searched words. Through googling I found FastPDFKit example for highlighting the searched words but they have used a third party library to achieve that. In my app I should not have to use third party API. I also found

```
//text positioning operators        
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(table, "Td", &op_Td);
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(table, "TD", &op_TD);
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(table, "Tm", &op_Tm);
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(table, "T*", &op_T);
```

But not getting how to write call back methods (&op_Td, &op_TD, &op_Tm, &op_T)for finding the position of the searched text and how to highlight it???? Do anyone have code for this?? Any help on this will be very helpful.

Thank You :)

Comment: @AAAAAAAAA U mean cant do it??

Comment: upto now no result for getting coordinates from pdf in our ios..